# "The latest build can't be fetched" message on smart git

Tags: smartgit

I am running `Smart git version 17.0.6 #10148` in my `Linux Mint` OS. Nowadays, I am continuously getting a message saying

> **The latest build can't be fetched.**
>
> Build 11190 requires an upgrade of your installation at /usr/share/smartgit.
>
> Please get the latest build from the website and install manually.

**Giving the screenshot below**

[image]

I don't have any issues with pull, push and other functionalities.

**Will this message turn to some serious issues in the future? How can I overcome this?**

Comment: That doesn't look right. Please shutdown SmartGit (Repository|Exit), get rid of ~/.smartgit/updates, restart SmartGit and try again.

Comment: @mstrap, Thanks for your time and reply. Do I need to delete `~/.smartgit/updates`? Will it affect Smartgit in any manner?

Comment: Yes, just delete it. It will set SmartGit back to the original installation (without any downloaded patches). I guess you are running the Community version of SmartGit?